# repeated measures contingency

Tags: repeated-measures, chi-squared-test

I've done an experiment of 20 mice where I added a drug to see if I can invoke a phenotype not otherwise present.  I did the experiment 4 times.  The control is always 0 or 1, but in the treatment group I get the event between 2-4 times.  Its never significant below 0.05 but the trend is clear.  is there a way to account for the probability that every time I do this experiment I get my observed event at a higher frequency of the baseline control?  I don't want to pool the four experiments (80 mice)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Regarding "its never significant", it turns out that based on what you've described, there are actually many relevant statistical tests, and it would be helpful for us to know which one is giving you p-values you don't like :)

Comment: Thanks! and when you say "never significant", does that mean you're running the test 4 times, one for each experiment?

Comment: no I'm randomizing 20 mice injected with tumour cells - and then treating 10 and not treating the other 10.  when I repeat the experiment, its brand new mice with brand new cells.

Comment: i meant statistical test

Comment: ah so sorry - yes that's correct I run a fisher exact test 4 times, one for each experiment.  thanks so much!

Comment: yeah friend that's why you're not getting significance; you want to use a single test on all of your data pooled together. Unfortunately, this is less straightforward. Your suggestion to just treat your data as 4 observations, where each obesrvation is just "did treatment outperform control" and run a test on those makes sense, but the trouble is (if the mental calculations I just did are right) that it is mathematically impossible to get a p-value less than 0.05 with only 4 observations using the standard binomial test (the smallest pvalue is 1/2^4 = 0.06ish)

Comment: in your shoes, I would compute this p value regardless and state that this does not reach the standard bar of statistical significance but is the smallest p value possible given the underpowered sample.

Comment: Wow ok thanks so much!!!  That’s really helpful